# cloned elements cannot be selected after jquery customSelect plugin installation

Tags: clone, drop-down-menu

I am in a bit of a pickle with this form and i would really appreciate some help.

After installing the customSelect() jquery plugin, i was no longer able to select the cloned select box elements on my form.

For an example, go to...

http:// gator1016.hostgator.com  /~tamarind/index.php/en/book-now.html

Click on the second slide >> click on the "add a package" button >> try and change one of the cloned select box values.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is? I'm under a bit of pressure to get this fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there= is no add a package button on the second slide

Comment: have u tried calling customSelect after the clone again? The problem with these plugins is that they are only added to the DOM at the time of calling. IF you add an element, you need to call the plugin again on those elements

Comment: hi. Thanks for your reply. i tried to add the jQuery('select').customSelect() call into the .click() event (associated with the "add another package" button), but when i did that, i couldn't select anything. My knowledge of jquery is basic and so i don't know if i am putting it in the right place.

Comment: where's the add_package_button click call

Comment: On another note, try using another select plugin like chosen. This one looks new and Incomplete

Comment: hmmm. i see. This is the second method i have tried and so i'd rather not replace the plugin. it took me long enough add this one to my forms. What makes you think it is new and incomplete? This is the one i used http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect Perhaps someone can offer a solution before i install something else. thanks

Comment: Try chosen jquery. also show me the call of add_package_button. Maybe that'll help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running .customSelect() in a seperate script tags **previous** to the rest of your form script. So here is the current order of events:

1. customSelect takes all given selects and appends a customizable `<span>` next to each (this is what you styled to achieve the desired look). It also attaches event listeners to those very spans so they can properly interact with their corresponding select element.
2. A user clicks "add another package", you clone the entire block of form elements **including** the custom spans that the plugin appended.

It is important to note that in doing this, you are not copying the event listeners, just the elements. Right now, even if you ran customSelect again upon cloning, you would likely have some kind of issue because the original span would still be there.

The  solution to your problem would be to keep a reference to a clone of your form block that has not already had customSelect applied. Then each time you insert a new form block, you need to apply customSelect to the "vanilla" form block.

Here is a reduced example for you

**HTML**

```
<form action="" id="myForm">
    <div id="formBlock">
        <select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>
    </div>
</form>

<button id="addNew">add new</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
//do this first:
var formBlock = $('#formBlock').clone();

//now .customSelect();
$('#formBlock select').customSelect();


$('#addNew').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newFormBlock = formBlock.clone().appendTo('#myForm'); //clone the reference to un-modified form block!!!
    newFormBlock.attr({
        id:'' //dont want duplicate id's
    });
    newFormBlock.find('select').customSelect();
});
```

> **Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/adamco/ZZGJZ/1/

Comment: Brilliant! I used your code (with a few modifications) and all seems to work :) Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You also can cleanup the elements added by the plugin, and launch again customSelect:

```
    $('form').find('span.customselect').remove(); //remove the span
    $('form').find('select.hasCustomSelect').removeAttr("style"); //clean inline style
    $('form select').customSelect( { customClass: "customselect" } ); // fire again customSelect
```